# Fetch DB password from a web service in Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, hikaricp

I have a specific requirement where in i need to fetch the database password  (spring.datasource.password=) from a secure vault through a web service call.

But the problem is that when i start my spring boot application it tries to make a Hikari connection pool.

How can i acheive this ?

Answer (score 0):

### Option one

You can override Spring's autoconfiguration by creating `DataSource` bean in your configuration.

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource(HikariConfig hikariConfig) {
    return new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig);
}

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "prefix")
public HikariConfig hirariConfig() {
    HicariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
    // password retrieve logic
    config.setPassword(password);
    return config;
}
```

### Option two

If you want to utilize Spring's autoconfigured `DataSource`, you can also use Spring Cloud Vault, which can lookup properties in Vault. Here are some tutorials which may help you to get started: https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-vault, https://spring.io/guides/gs/vault-config/.

### Other options

You can inject your password as an environment variable. This variable should be named `SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD`. Or you can create your own `PropertySource` which will supply needed variable.

You can find more about this option in [Spring blog](https://spring.io/blog/2020/04/23/spring-tips-configuration).